# Change the value for a Restapi using Foreach

Tags: php

I'm using rottentomatoes API 
and  Would like to change the title to uppercase but it works just a few Movies not for all,

```
foreach ($movies as $v) {

    $name = strtoupper($v->name);

}
```

the $movies has an json code like

```
   { 
  "id": 770672122, 
     "name": "Toy Story 3",
   }
```

I have a list of 43 items and just change the name for the first 5 items and not for all what happen with the rest?
there a way to understand why thing is happend?
How can I change the value for all data?
Thanks

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: It's no the first time that this happen to me ... it just change the data for the first 5 movies and the others still in lowercase

Comment: Can you please make an example like: What is in `$movies` ?(`var_dump($movies)`) And what is the output after the `foreach` loop?

Comment: the output is a json code like 
{
  "id": 770672122,
  "name": "Toy Story 3",
  "year": 2010,
  "genres": [
    "Animation",
    "Kids & Family",
    "Science Fiction & Fantasy",
    "Comedy"
}
and I want to change the name for all movies

Comment: it works just for the firtly 5 or 6 and no for all there are 43 items